# Output Resistance of Small-Signal MOSFET Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, cmos, small-signal

I have some doubts concerning the calculation of the small-signal output resistance of a common-source stage with source-degeneration. This is related to another question I posted but I have refined my question in detail here as to exactly what is troubling me

### The Problem

Calculate the small-signal output resistance of the following circuit including the effect of channel-length modulation and ignoring the body effect.

[image]

### My Solution

I have two approaches to find the output small-signal resistance, they both involve,

- Drawing the small-signal model of the circuit
- Zero all independent sources (voltage sources = short, current sources = opens)
- Applying a voltage Vx at the output and measure the resulting current Ix flowing.
- Output resistance will then be Rout = Vx/Ix

This gives us the following circuit
[image]

Now from here on, I have two approaches - the first approach gives me the correct answer, however the second approach gives me an incorrect answer.

#### Approach 1 (KVL)

[image]

#### Approach 2 (Resistors)

[image]

**Why does my second approach give me an incorrect answer?** I suspect it is something to do with the fact that the ro now only gets a current Ix flowing through it.? Something that didn't sit well with me in the second approach was that after decomposing the current source into a resistor, I had to get rid of the negative sign of the 1/gm. So current flow direction is strange to me too.

EDIT:
Extra Info for Comments:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have already told you why: you can't make transform `gm*Vs` into a fixed resistor because `Vs` varies with `I(Rs)`. Your approach implies a fixed `Vs`, but that's one possibility out of an infinity. If `Vs` is fixed then yes, you can equivalate `gm*Vs` with a fixed resistor, but that will only be true for that particular value of `Vs`. As long as there is current flowing through `Rs`, the voltage level at the source will change, with or without `Vgs`.

Comment: I agree with @aconcernedcitizen. When I got to the part in your derivation where you equate the a current source with a resistor, my mind went "huh?"

Comment: Not only, but even if the calculations with the first approach are OK, in the 3rd picture the current Ix circulating inside ro is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I think I understand it now. Apologies for so many questions. @barrow The current circulating in the loop is between the VCCS and ro is gmvgs before the sign of vgs has been taken into account.

Comment: @AlfroJang80, please, look attentively to your third picture. It shows a current Ix circulating inside ro. Well, this is completely wrong and confusing.

Comment: @barrow There are two currents flowing through ro - the loop formed by the VCCS causing gmvgs to flow through it and Ix which flows through ro and then to Rs. Maybe the colours I used are not clear. The flow of Ix is : Vx to ro to Rs to GND. The only other current in that circuit is the VCCS current whose flow is : VCCS to ro to VCCS and circulates there. The KVL equations below the drawing should clarify what I mean.

Comment: @barrow Ix does not circulate in ro, it simply flows through ro. the VCCS current is circulating in ro. I have also attached an explanation from the book about this in the original post. I hope this clears things up! I'll use better colours next time!

Comment: @AlfroJang80, absolutely no. With the test supply Vx you are injecting the current Ix on the first node and the same current Ix is entering in Rs. This is OK. But in the resistor ro you have both the contribution of Ix (positive) and that of the VCCS (negative). Instead you've drawn a current Ix (in yellow) passing through ro, and this is wrong! Anyway, it is only a matter of clarity...

Comment: Infact, according to your drawing, it seems that the current Ix leaves the node and directly enter through ro, and this is wrong (or not so clear, at least). Can you see it now?

Comment: Besides, the current direction of VCCS is already indicated fron its symbol, so there is no need to indicate it again by using the arrow... this is another thing not so clear in your drawing.

Comment: @barrow Sorry for so many questions. So it is not necessarily true that all of the Ix flows through ro? Some of it may flow through VCCS? I'm getting confused why the author has put all of Ix in his equation for ro?

Comment: I was trying to think about it for an impedance point of view. What is the impedance seen by the Ix current to define where Ix flows?. But what is the series (not shunt) impedance that Ix sees due to the current source?

Comment: See my comments [there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/553932/how-does-current-flow-in-this-circuit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written "Current source whose current depends on voltage across it = resistor".

This is true, as long as the current is linearly proportional to the voltage across the current source.

However, the voltage across that current source is \$V_{ds}\$, while its current is proportional to \$V_{gs}\$. Thus, the current is not proportional to the voltage *across the current source*, and replacing it with a resistor is invalid.

Comment: Got it! It seemed slightly weird to me as well because the new "resistor" I had gotten had a negative value. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @AlfroJang80 It'd be perfectly normal, in the general case, to get a negative value resistor from doing this. In the specific case of a transistor model, though, you certainly can't have it producing power out of nowhere.